# IP address that can not be reached from outside of device

Tags: ipv4, ip, ip-address, loopback

I am sorry if this is a silly question, but I am developing an application that should connect to itself over sockets, but to make it secure it should only be reachable from local device. I believe I am looking for `127.0.0.1`, but I am not sure. Could someone confirm if this IP address is unreachable from any outside IP address?

Comment: You may find it helpful to run `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` to get your network IP and see if that address can be reached by another computer on the network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` block can never appear anywhere on any network, nor can any address in that block be used as a source or destination address for packets outside the host.

The goes back at least as far as [*RFC 990, ASSIGNED NUMBERS*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc990):

> The class A network number 127 is assigned the "loopback" function,
> that is, a datagram sent by a higher level protocol to a network 127
> address should loop back inside the host.  No datagram "sent" to a
> network 127 address should ever appear on any network anywhere.

[*RFC 1122, Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Communication Layers*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3):

> (g)  { 127,  }
>
> Internal host loopback address.  Addresses of this form MUST NOT
> appear outside a host.

Also [*RFC 3330, Special-Use IPv4 Addresses*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330):

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an
> address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host.
> This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback,
> but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network
> anywhere [RFC1700, page 5].