# dpctl: OpenFlow packet receive failed: unexpected end of file

Tags: sdn, openflow, mininet

I'm doing some experiment with SDN and pox controller, I have written flows manually shown below:

```
dpctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:6653 in_port=10,actions=output:14  
dpctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:6653 in_port=14,actions=output:10
```

But when i want to see my flows using dump-flows command, I get the error `dpctl: OpenFlow packet receive failed: unexpected end of file` 
Does anyone know what the problem could be or where to start to troubleshoot?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are trying to use a flow based on the loopback address. See the answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/50583/8499) to understand why any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` block can never be seen on any network anywhere.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found good advice about your case:
https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/openflow-discuss/2013-April/004537.html

Also see this part of [man](http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-dpctl.8.txt) ovs-dpctl:

> This program works only with datapaths that are implemented outside  of
>          ovs-vswitchd  itself,  such as the Linux and Windows kernel-based data‐
>          paths.  To manage datapaths that are integrated into ovs-vswitchd, such
>          as  the  userspace  (netdev)  datapath, use ovs-appctl(8) to invoke the
>          dpctl/* commands, which are documented in ovs-vswitchd(8).

Also you may try to use this tool to see flows:

http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.txt

```
dump-flows switch [flows]
          Prints  to  the console all flow entries in switch's tables that
          match flows.  If flows is omitted, all flows in the  switch  are
          retrieved.   See  Flow  Syntax,  below, for the syntax of flows.
          The output format is described in Table Entry Output.

          By default, ovs-ofctl prints flow entries in the same order that
          the switch sends them, which is unlikely to be intuitive or con‐
          sistent.  Use --sort and --rsort to control display order.   The
          --names/--no-names  and  --stats/--no-stats  options also affect
          output formatting.  See the descriptions of these options, under
          OPTIONS below, for more information
```